# How to do an average of computed column

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

I have data in a table called transaction, I have derived purchase value i.e `final_rat1 * quantity` and sum of purchase quantity

```
Buysell     Quantity    Final_rat1 
B           50          88.14
B           230         88.14
B           75          88.14
B           87          88.14
B           187         88.14
B           150         88.14
B           221         88.14
```

Below is the code for it, but when I am averaging purchase value / sum of purchase quantity I'm unable to get proper average. Could you please guide me on this. Below is the code, which I have mentioned

```
sum(case
        when sauda.buysell = 'B' then
            sauda.quantity * 1
        else
            0
        end) as "P.Qty",
sum(case
        when sauda.buysell = 'B' then
            sauda.quantity * (sauda.final_rat1 + sauda.brokpercontract)
        else
            0
        end) As "P.value",
sum(case
        when sauda.buysell = 'B' then
            sauda.quantity * (sauda.final_rat1 + sauda.brokpercontract)/sauda.quantity
        else
            0
        end) as "P.Avg"
```

Actual Average should be 88.14 where as i m getting an average of 616.98 and if i remove the sum from below average query

```
case
    when sauda.buysell = 'B' then
        sauda.quantity * (sauda.final_rat1 + sauda.brokpercontract)/sauda.quantity
    else
        0
    end as "P.Avg"
```

it says "not a group by function"

Comment: update question with adding `brokpercontract` column also in posted table data..

Comment: sauda.quantity * (sauda.final_rat1 + sauda.brokpercontract)/sauda.quantity would effectively give you sauda.final_rat1 + sauda.brokpercontract only right? Make your question clearer, and what is this column brokpercontract ? add that too.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean something like this:

```
sum(case
    when sauda.buysell = 'B' then
        sauda.quantity * 1
    else
        0
    end) as "P.Qty",
sum(case
    when sauda.buysell = 'B' then
        sauda.quantity * (sauda.final_rat1 + sauda.brokpercontract)
    else
        0
    end) As "P.value",
avg(case
    when sauda.buysell = 'B' then
        sauda.final_rat1 + sauda.brokpercontract
    else
        0
    end) as "P.Avg"
```